# What is the difference between a static library and a command line application?

Tags: static-libraries, executable

I know that command line apps are standalone and can be called from a shell. Static libraries on the other hand are linked to by other programs.

But what actually is the difference between the two? Is it the same binary with a different interface? Or is it something different altogether?

Comment: What? This is literally comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: One not necessarily needs a shell to run/start (any) program.

Comment: Not sure why the down votes. The same code can be compiled into both a standalone application or into a static library. I'm trying to understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

It is something different altogether. A standalone application has a binary product that can directly be executed. Static libraries however cannot be executed on their own. A standalone application may link to a set of static libraries in which case the symbols defined in those libraries will be accessible to the application.

To give you an example, you can create a static library which declares the following function in `helper.h` and defines it in `helper.c`:

```
int func() {
    printf("hi\n");
}
```

When you build this library, you will end up with something like `helper.a` which cannot be executed independently (it doesn't have `int main()`) but can be linked to by one or multiple standalone applications. Once linked, those applications can simply include `helper.h` and call `func()` as if they have implemented `func()`.

In the end, choosing between the two depends on what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to create a tool that multiple applications can link to and use? Then go with static library.

Comment: Here "*Once linked, those applications can simply include helper.h and call func() as if they have implemented func().*" the order is wrong. Start with including the header, (then compile,) then link the library, then and only then run the program which finally calls `func()`.

Comment: That is right. Based on his question, I was assuming the OP is using Xcode in which linking is done via build settings.

Comment: "*linking is done via build settings*" how would this change the necessary order? Linking is the *last* step during the build.

Comment: @alk The order is always compile first, link after; just as you mentioned. Linking phase in Xcode is after compiling the source code. No need to explicitly specify the steps.